# How is @RepositoryDefinition different from extending Repository?

Tags: java, spring-data

Here's what the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) says:

> If you do not want to extend Spring Data interfaces, you can also annotate your repository interface with `@RepositoryDefinition`. Extending one of the CRUD repository interfaces exposes a complete set of methods to manipulate your entities. If you prefer to be selective about the methods being exposed, copy the methods you want to expose from the CRUD repository into your domain repository.

But in order to be selective about which methods to expose, I may also simply extend `Repository` (which is a marker interface)

In other words, is there any difference between

```java
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = Card.class, idClass = UUID.class)
public interface BareBonesCardRepository {
    List<Card> findByAccountId(UUID accountId);
}
```

and

```java
public interface BareBonesCardRepository extends Repository<Card, UUID> {
    List<Card> findByAccountId(UUID accountId);
}
```

?

Comment: It is basically the same thing.
Check this doc :- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/RepositoryDefinition.html

Comment: Difference is we can choose particular methods to be exposed, instead of exposing all methods in Repository.

Comment: @Jiandong which are none (it's a marker interface)

Comment: ohh yes, yes, you are right. @Kodigas